# “Ferme-la” and “ferme-le”?

Tags: sens, impératif, ellipse

French for ‘shut up’ is ‘ferme-la (bouche)’. However, I have come across ‘ferme-le’ which, judging from the context, could mean something similar.  I have tried googling for it but came up with nothing. Is this some kind of frequent typo, or legitimate ellipsis, or yet something else... Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As *la* is a pronoun, not an adverb, that must be *Ferme-la !*, not *ferme-là !* as it was initially written in the title. *La* is not an article either. The meaning is not *ferme la bouche* but *ferme-la, ta bouche (more likely: gueule)*. A stronger synonymous of *ferme la !* is *ta gueule !*. In addition to the hypothetical masculine antecedent that have been listed, there is also the possibility that the person you heard had a *picard* (a.k.a *chti*) accent, where *la* might be pronounced like *lo* and thus confused with *le*.

Comment: @jlliagre Many thanks. I understand that I made a mistake in writing là (not an adverb, as you say); i did assume that it was the article left after the elision of the noun, but now realise that it is in fact a clitic pronoun. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Plusieurs possibilités pour un nom masculin :

- CLAPET (~1947 in *Mollo sur la joncaille*...)
- CLAQUE-MERDE (in *Les tontons flingueurs*...)
- CLAQUET (in *Winter*...)
- BEC (~1908 in *Pieds Nickelés au Mexique*...)
- PLOMB (~1897 in *Hors des lois*...)
- SUCRIER (~1925 in *La bonne vie*...)
- MOULIN (à parole) (~1927 in *À la revoyure*...)
- RIDEAU (~1975)

Noter tout de même que si *ferme-**la*** se comprendra, dans le contexte d'un dialogue, en tant que tel et sans nécessité que le mot *bouche* apparaisse précédemment, *ferme-**le*** ne sera immédiatement compris dans ce sens que si un des mots ci-dessus est explicitement présent dans la proposition qui précède (ou suit).

Et noter aussi que la plupart de ces tournures appartient au registre de l'argot.